# IE6 inline-block not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Hi I have tried for 2 hours everything that I could find on the net with this to no avail. So my last hope resides here.
You can check the site at:
http://webofdreams.ro/vworker/finemaid/finemaid.html#
the navigation is overview and services.

html:

```
        <div class="contentNav clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a class="show1 navButton" class="left" id="activeLink">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a class="show2 navButton" class="right">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

css:

```
.clearfix {clear: both;}
.contentNav {
    color: #ddd !important;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    }
.contentNav a { 
    color: #fff !important;
    }
.navButton {
    font-size: 18px !important;;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: rgb(122,188,255); /* Old browsers */    
    }
.contentNav li {
    display: inline-block;
    }
/*IE specific css*/
.navButton {
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    }
.navButton a {
    zoom: 1;
    *display:inline;
    }
.height {
    height: 45px;
    clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: as a web developer myself, I don't check IE6 anymore

Comment: Couldn't agree more with Phil. Drop IE6 support. It's more than dead by now. Besides, no one uses IE6 anymore. Apart from some web developers who want to see how their site looks like in IE6.

Comment: Unfortunately, depending on the client scope, that simply isn't true. I've had issues recently with a client having visitors using IE5. Depending on the project, said issues might be unacceptable. What isn't working viktor?

Comment: Nobody uses IE6? A lot of the big Fortune 500 I has to support at my old job still used it.

Comment: @viktor - What exactly is not working? Your question isn't clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I could not agree more with the IE6 still being asked by the clients, also I am sorry I have not been more thorough with the question. I try to have a short navigation with 2 elements centered near each other in the center of the page. In IE however the 2 buttons are on top of each other and I can't make them be on the same line, no matter what I tried. You can check the site at:http://webofdreams.ro/vworker/finemaid/finemaid.html# the 2 links are overview si services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE only supports `display: inline-block` for elements that are natively `inline`. `<li>` elements are natively `block`, so in IE, you need to keep it as `display: inline`, but trigger `hasLayout` on the element, like so:

```
display:-moz-inline-stack;  /* only for older mozilla browsers */
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;  /* triggers hasLayout */
*display:inline;  /* resets element to inline for IE */
```

Here's the article I found this solution on some time ago:

[Cross Browser Support for inline-block Styling](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/)

That said, I've never tested this in IE6, because IE6 is 11 years old and shouldn't be supported anymore. But it's worth a shot. The article was written in '07, so he may have tested in IE6

Comment: I have found the same article and tried this solution, but it does not work.

Comment: and you applied these styles to your `.contentNav li` tags? The CSS you posted above shows that the `<li>` tags only have `display: inline`, without the IE workarounds. You use them on `.navButton` and `.navButton a`, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: does anyone read the code? the li has the navButton class which has the IE workaround.

Comment: @viktor No, your `li` tags have no class. your `a` tags have the .navButon class.